# How many ways to represent a 3 binary digit number that starts with 1 XOR ends with 0?

Tags: combinatorics

Borrowing from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369466/how-many-bit-strings-of-length-8-start-with-00-or-end-with-1).
How many ways are there to represent a 3 binary digit number that starts with 1 XOR ends with 0?
I calculated the following:

- number of ways to start with 1xx :$2^2$
- number of ways to end with xx0: $2^2$
- number of ways for both 1x0 : $2^1$

Mathematically I got the answer as $2^2 +2^2-2^1 = 6$
but using a tree diagram I found only **4 possible combinations**: that is
**101
111
000
010**

I would like some help to pinpoint where I went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones that both start with 1 and end in 0 are represented twice in the two larger groups; excluding them once makes it so they are counted once, suitable for OR.  But XOR needs the conjunction to be counted no times: subtract it out twice.